# Implementing formula and Sigma Sum into Java?

Tags: java

How would i implement something like this into java:

[image]

Here is my attempt so far:

```
float yPos = (float) ((Q* A) * D.y * Math.cos(w.y * (D.dot(x,y)) + phase_const * t));
```

Im confused as to how i could implement something like Sigma or Sum() or wiDi.(x,y) not sure if i implemented it correctly.

Thank you

Comment: You can implement it in Java by calling Matlab from Java :D

Comment: I really wish i could man hahah. Matlab. I remember those days. :P Engineering 2nd year...

Comment: Sigma would easiest be done in java 8: `IntStream.range(0, n).mapToDouble(i -> cos(i)).sum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're certainly not going to get that into one line of code.  ;-)

I don't know what this math is doing, but let me suggest an approach.

It looks like in the various sigma expressions there are various objects (Q, A, D, etc) that have the same number of elements, which are to be iterated by the subscript 'i'.

Those objects appear to be created at some point, remaining constant while the 'P' function is applied over a variety of x, y, and t values.

This suggests that you need a 'Calculator' class, that takes those objects (Q, A, D, etc.) as constructor parameters.  (Or perhaps computes them in the constructor.)

Your Calculator.P() function is then parameterized by x, y, and t values, and returns a triple of values.  (I'm not sure if this is meant to be talking about Points, but use a suitable 3-valued object.)

The body of P then just becomes 3 loops of "for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)", computing the sum each of those expressions.

In short, have a class that takes the invariants as constructor parameters, so they can be stored for use on each invocation of P, and put all the parameterized computations into the P function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response :) The method is form this source:       http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch01.html            I am attempting to simulate water using the gerstner method. This method creates waves

Comment: Here is what im am currently working on: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69824/3d-water-simulation-formula-questions/69826?noredirect=1#69826

Comment: That looks like a fun problem.  So, the Q, A, etc. are actually parameters of the individual waves, and the i iterates through the waves. So, the GerstnerWaveCalculator holds a number of Waves, and can compute a modified vertex position for any given (x, y, t).  Presumably then the wave parameters could then be individually tweaked over time as well.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

The formula contains matrix operations that are expensive to code from scratch each time. Use some matrix library like [Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/), for instance, to perform matrix operations. Sums are trivial to compute.

Also, some commercial packages like Maple can generate Java (C actually but conversion is easy) code to perform vector, matrix and other operations from the formulas like you give above.

Comment: Im using JMonkey, so there a built in methods for Vectors like Vector.dot(Vector) or Vector.mult(Vector) the only issue is i dont know how to implement it properly.